How do assigmnents and namespaces work in the debugging console?
I have this code (including line numbers):
1   a = 1
2   
3   def output():
4       print(a)
5   
6   output()
7   print(a)

Running the code prints 1 and 1, as expected.
When setting a breakpoint in line 4 and executing a = 9 on the debugging console, I would have expected the see 9 and 1 printed when letting the debugger run. Instead, I still get 1 and 1.
Then I tried the same, but now entered global a and then a = 9 on the debugging console after hitting the breakpoint. In this case, I would have expected to see 9 and 9 when letting the debugger run, but again, I see 1 and 1.
So I wonder how assignments and namespaces are dealt with when using the debugging console. I always thought that what I enter there will be executed just as if it was a line in the source file (apart from exception handling).
I use Visual Studio Code and tried it with Python 3.10 and 3.11.

global statements are processed when compiling the code. Executing it in the debugger doesn't affect how the function was compiled.
